# Indicate which corresponding columns have a TRUE indicator

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(
  identifer=c(1,2,3,4),
  DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Suspension","System"),
  DF_source1=c("Capsule","Powder,Metered","Tablet",NA),
  DF_source2=c(NA,NA,"Tablet",NA),
  DF_source3=c("Tablet, Extended Release","Liquid","Tablet",NA),
  Route_source1=c("Oral","INHALATION","Oral",NA),
  Route_source2=c(NA,"TOPICAL","Oral",NA),
  Route_source3=c("Oral","IRRIGATION","oral",NA))
```

I want to know which DF_source matches DF, and additionally which associated Route I should take.

I want the output to look like this:

```
df_out<-data.frame(
  identifer=c(1,2,3,4),
  DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Suspension","System"),
  DF_match=c("Tablet, Extended Release","Powder,Metered;Powder",NA,NA),
  Route_match=c("Oral","INHALATION;TOPICAL",NA,NA),
  DF_match_count=c(1,2,0,0),
  DF_route_count=c(1,2,0,0))
```

I tried this but I'm not sure how to pull values for DF_match and Route_ Match

```
df%>%mutate_at(vars(matches("(DF_source)")),
                         list(string_detect = ~str_detect(tolower(DF),tolower(str_replace_all(.,"/|,(\\s)?|(?<!,)\\s","|")))))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you have in mind, but hope this might help.

Your end result appears not to match your example data (e.g. TOPICAL is missing).

This might be easier in a tidier form with `pivot_longer`.

**Edit**: If columns are factors, convert to character for `str_detect` in `filter`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(identifer, DF), names_to = c(".value", "number"), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)") %>%
  filter(str_detect(DF_source, DF)) %>%
  group_by(identifer) %>%
  summarise(DF_match = paste(DF_source, collapse = ';'),
            Route_match = paste(Route_source, collapse = ';'),
            match_count = n()) %>%
  right_join(df[,c("identifer", "DF")], by = "identifer") %>%
  select(c(identifer, DF, DF_match, Route_match, match_count))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  identifer DF         DF_match                 Route_match        match_count
      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>                    <chr>                    <int>
1         1 Tablet     Tablet, Extended Release Oral                         1
2         2 Powder     Powder,Metered;Powder    INHALATION;TOPICAL           2
3         3 Suspension NA                       NA                          NA
4         4 System     NA                       NA                          NA
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. I coudn't find the function pivot_table

Comment: yep, sorry meant pivot_longer but for some reason it's not showing up when I download that library

Comment: Can you describe the problem further? `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` became available with version 1.0.0. What version do you have? And did you load the library after downloading?

Comment: Are you available for chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215707/room-for-ben-and-mel

Comment: Thank you for helping me download +update my package Ben. For this part of the code "filter(str_detect(DF_source, DF))" it says that Error in type(pattern) : object 'DF' not found

Comment: Shall we go back to chat?